# Issues with mod_rewrite do single php file

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with directing all requests to one single php file. I used the setup before.

The configuration in C:/path/app/.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex  disabled

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php    [QSA,L]
```

The error logs

```
[Fri Apr 19 07:04:04.582078 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4804:tid 1284] mod_rewrite.c(466): [client 127.0.0.1:65174] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#238bf48][rid#2d9e170/initial] [perdir C:/path/app/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/path/app/ -> 
[Fri Apr 19 07:04:04.582078 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4804:tid 1284] mod_rewrite.c(466): [client 127.0.0.1:65174] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#238bf48][rid#2d9e170/initial] [perdir C:/path/app/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[Fri Apr 19 07:04:04.582078 2013] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4804:tid 1284] mod_rewrite.c(466): [client 127.0.0.1:65174] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#238bf48][rid#2d9e170/initial] [perdir C:/path/app/] rewrite '' -> 'web/index.php'
[Fri Apr 19 07:04:04.582078 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4804:tid 1284] mod_rewrite.c(466): [client 127.0.0.1:65174] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#238bf48][rid#2d9e170/initial] [perdir C:/path/app/] add per-dir prefix: web/index.php -> C:/path/app/web/index.php
[Fri Apr 19 07:04:04.582078 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 4804:tid 1284] mod_rewrite.c(466): [client 127.0.0.1:65174] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#238bf48][rid#2d9e170/initial] [perdir C:/path/app/] internal redirect with C:/path/app/web/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

And the file C:/path/app/web/index.php exists and is only the phpinfo().

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

If I get the logs rights, the redirect is working as expected, but I still get a 404.

**Any ideas what might be the issue here?**

Comment: Firstly decide you want to `Rewrite` or `Redirect` all url's ?

Comment: Shouldn't one of the lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` instead?

Comment: @MarkParnell +1. I also like to check for symlinks `!-l`

Comment: @Rikesh Rewrite is correct. I want to map all incoming request to one file, but there is no redirect in the brower.

Comment: @MarkParnell and Phil Thanks for the hints, but that still don't fix my core issues. According the log the redirect works, but I get a 404 anyway.

Comment: Put an `echo "<h1>something</h1>";` as first line in `web/index.php` and see if that gets printed. I think `web/index.php` might also be doing some redirects using PHP code.

Comment: @anubhava This was my first idea, thats why I reduced it to the phpinfo();

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice that your `web/index.php` only has this line: `phpinfo();` So is this `phpinfo();` output being displayed?

Comment: Also is this your complete `.htaccess`? Also is there any .htaccess in `web/` folder as well?

Comment: Only if I call http://localhost/app/web/index.php directly, not with any other url.

Comment: @mnhg: Is your .htaccess even working? Put some garbage text on top and see if it generates 500 for you.

Comment: Yes. Proved this already with the DirectoryIndex directive. And the logs are confirming that the redirect is done.

Comment: What's your web server root folder ? Maybe you need to set `RewriteBase /app/web/` right after `RewriteEngine on` ?

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php    [QSA,L]` or RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/web/index.php    [QSA,L]

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard you right. I added `RewriteBase /app/` and it works. Please create an answer from you comment so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rules need to know the folder base (web server root by default).

So you need to set `RewriteBase /app/` right after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php    [QSA,L]
```